# Evaluate \$(\overline ABC\oplus A\overline B) + (\overline AB)\$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I'm struggling with evaluating this one:

> \$(\overline ABC\oplus A\overline B) + (\overline AB)\$

I've got to

> \$A\oplus  B + A\overline B \overline C +\overline ABC\$

But how do I prove that \$A\overline B \overline C +\overline ABC = 0\$

Edit: The answer is \$A\oplus B\$

Comment: +1 for properly figuring out mathJax for boolean algebra. The anwering people can take an example from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A⊕B is AB(Bar)+A(bar)B
```

So the Expanded equation is

```
AB(Bar)+A(bar)B+AB(bar)C(bar)+A(bar)BC
```

Taking Common factors out

```
A(bar)B(1+C(bar))+AB(bar)(1+C)
```

1+ anything is always 1

So we Have `A(bar)B+AB(bar)` which is `A(exor)B`

Comment: Always Welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer:

[image]

Hope this help